# How can I display page controller only on the first launch IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I want to display the page controller only the first time when users opens the app, and after that when he opens again, then it skips the page controller and directly move to the Home Screen.

Here is the code -

```
import UIKit

class PageVC: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

lazy var VCArr: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.VCInstance(name: "FirstVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name: "SecondVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name: "ThirdVC")]
}()

private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    if let firstVC = VCArr.first {
        setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view is UIScrollView {
            view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        } else if view is UIPageControl {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return VCArr.last
    }

    guard VCArr.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return VCArr[previousIndex]
}

public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

    guard nextIndex < VCArr.count else {
        return VCArr.first
    }

    guard VCArr.count > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return VCArr[nextIndex]
}

public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return VCArr.count
}


public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
        let firstViewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: firstViewController) else {
            return 0
    }

    return firstViewControllerIndex
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `UserDefaults` to set a `Bool` value which defines if is the first time the App is opened.

So before present the page you ask for the value in `UserDefaults`, If the value doesn't exists you set it.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set( true, forKey: "firstTimeOpened")
```

**EDITED**

I suppose your `Home View Controller`is `FirstVC`so try this:

In your `FirstVC`on the `ViewDidAppear`function:

```
let firstTime = UserDefaults.standard().object(ForKey: "first_time") as? Bool // Here you look if the Bool value exists, if not it means that is the first time the app is opened

// Show the intro collectionView
if firstTime == nil {
    let view = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourPageVC") // Instatiates your pageView
    show(view, sender: nil)
    UserDefaults.standard().set(false, forKey: "first_time")
}
```

After that you can dismiss your `PageView` and return to home, if you restart your app the PageView will not appear.

Comment: Can you help me implement it in my code i am new to swift

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidiLoad method of page controller just call (push/present) home screen controller without any animation effect.

Or set Home screen as rootviewController with Navigation Controller

like this:
    class func setHomeScreen(){
        var mainView: UIStoryboard!
        mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "HomeScreen", bundle: nil)
        let viewcontroller : UINavigationController = mainView.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeNavigationViewController") as! HomeNavigationViewController
        AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller

```
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are not pushing/preseting view controller, instead what u do is change root view controller